# Custom pages for authors using a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called `mycustompost` my permalink for the posts is `/mycustompost/%auth%/%post_id%` So that is working fine and if I go to '/mycustompost' I get archive page. What I want to be able to do is to go one level deeper.

Thus if I browse to `/mycustompost/admin` it will show all the posts for that author. Could someone point me to some examples of how to do this, my types are done in my plugin code.

Comment: You should reply to answers. Keeping quite will never get you problems solved. If the answer below solved your question, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your permalink structure to allow for the /mycustompost/admin or rather
/myposttype/mypostname

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite
Might be of assistance